# Display Values in PHP Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble displaying data from a PHP array. My array looks like this:

```
    Array
    (
        [July] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ETitle] => Launch Party
                        [EStart] => 2017-07-26T09:00:00
                        [EEnd] => 2017-04-28T17:00:00
                        [ELink] => http://example.dev/events/launch-party
                        [EStartMonth] => July
                        [EStartYear] => 2017
                    )

            )

        [August] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [ETitle] => Open Day
                        [EStart] => 2017-08-10T00:00:00
                        [EEnd] => 2017-08-11T00:00:00
                        [ELink] => http://example.dev/events/open-day
                        [EStartMonth] => August
                        [EStartYear] => 2017
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [ETitle] => Dama Google Event
                        [EStart] => 2017-08-20T02:00:00-07:00
                        [EEnd] => 2017-08-20T03:00:00-07:00
                        [EStartMonth] => August
                        [EStartYear] => 2017
                        [ELink] => https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NjdsZW9ydmE4bWlmOHRnZ3J0dGw3MTVlamIgcnY3YTZyMTlmMjQyMHZvcmFkcWNrbW1zdG9AZw
                    )

            )

    )
```

What i need to display on the page a list of items grouped under headings like this, formatted with html:

```
    <h2>July</h2>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://example.dev/events/launch-party">Launch Party</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Augast</h2>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://example.dev/events/open-day">Open Day</a></li>
    <!-- if link contains "google" string, link needs target attribute -->
    <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NjdsZW9ydmE4bWlmOHRnZ3J0dGw3MTVlamIgcnY3YTZyMTlmMjQyMHZvcmFkcWNrbW1zdG9AZw">Dama Google Event</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I have tried all sorts of solutions from stack overflow but I keep ending up with invalid index warnings when I try loop through recursively. How do I solve this, and build the HTML list as described?

**EDIT: updated expected result with real HTML**

Comment: Do you know `foreach` Loop?

Comment: Yes, I have tried lots of `foreach` loops and recursive functions but none of them work. I am just beginning to learn PHP.

Comment: Please provide the "HTML" result that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loops in PHP.

Let's say your array is stored in a variable called `$events`:

```
foreach ($events as $monthName => $month) {
  echo '<h2>' . $monthName . '</h2>';
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ($month as $event) {
    if (strpos(parse_url($event['ELink'], PHP_URL_HOST), 'google') !== false) {
      $target = ' target="_blank"';
    } else {
      $target = '';
    }
    echo '<li><a' . $target . ' href="' . $event['ELink'] . '">' . $event['ETitle'] . '</a></li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

I also added the `target="_blank"` attribute if the url host contains "google".

Try it out [here](https://eval.in/836406).

Comment: Yes, [your code works](https://eval.in/836403) , but he didn't provide the HTML he wants before your answer. He needs to change the HTML elements according to his needs

Comment: This was enough of a hint, and i've edited the original post with real HTML.

Comment: @Accountant yes, I edited my answer now after he edited his question.

Comment: @PeterMader Thanks for updating with the target attribute. What's the advantage of using `PHP_URL_HOST`? I simply did `(strpos($event['ELink'], 'google') !== false)` which works well enough, but please explain the advantages of your way. Is it safer?

Comment: Your solution will detect `example.dev?a=google` as a URL to a Google domain, although the domain is actually `example.dev`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Ah, of course, if google is anywhere in the URL, mine will ring true. Thanks for the hint. I just need the domain to be google, as you rightly thought. Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

How did you try the foreach loops? Here is a short example of how your array should look like in php to iterate through ist.

The outer foreach iterates the months and prints their name.
The second/inner foreach iterates through all events(?) in the month. The HTML output is just as an example.

```
<?php
$data = array (
    'July' => array(
            array(

                    'ETitle' => 'Launch Party',
                    'EStart' => '2017-07-26T09:00:00',
                    'EEnd' => '2017-04-28T17:00:00',
                    'ELink' => 'http://example.dev/events/launch-party',
                    'EStartMonth' => 'July',
                    'EStartYear' => 2017
                )

        ),

    'August' => array
        (
            array(

                    'ETitle' => 'Open Day',
                    'EStart' => '2017-08-10T00:00:00',
                    'EEnd' => '2017-08-11T00:00:00',
                    'ELink' => 'http://example.dev/events/open-day',
                    'EStartMonth' => 'August',
                    'EStartYear' => 2017
                ),

            array (

                    'ETitle' => 'Dama Google Event',
                    'EStart' => '2017-08-20T02:00:00-07:00',
                    'EEnd' => '2017-08-20T03:00:00-07:00',
                    'EStartMonth' => 'August',
                    'EStartYear' => 2017,
                    'ELink' => 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NjdsZW9ydmE4bWlmOHRnZ3J0dGw3MTVlamIgcnY3YTZyMTlmMjQyMHZvcmFkcWNrbW1zdG9AZw'
                )

        )

);

//echo '<pre>';
//var_dump($data);

$month = null;
foreach($data as $key => $dates) {
    if ($month !== $key) {
        $month = $key;
        echo '<h1>'.$month.'<h1>';
    }

    if (!empty($dates)) {
        foreach($dates as $data) {
            $title = (isset($data['ETitle'])) ? $data['ETitle'] : 'no title ???';
            $link = (isset($data['ELink'])) ? $data['ELink'] : '#';
            echo '<a href="'.$link.'">' . $title . '</a>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

You can test this example in [php sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/32db9c1398706337029f12ac451cece3c9501f31).